# troubling in building two code into one code in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var arr = [{
  val: 1,
  text: 'Option 1'
         }, {
  val: 2,
  text: 'Option 2'
        }];
         $(function () {
   $('a').click(function () {
      var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('body');
      $(arr).each(function () {
          sel.append($("<option>").val(this.val).text(this.text));
      });
      $('<br>').insertBefore(sel);
      $('<input/>').insertAfter(sel);
      return false;
  });
           });
          </script>

      </head>

      <body>

   <a href="">Add Select Box</a>
```

this is my first code.....what it do is that whenever i click  on anchor tag it displays a selectbox with options  - option 1 and option 2 as written above.....

now my second code is as follows...
what it doing is that on page load it displays a selectbox that is displaying values fetched from the database....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(function(){
      var items="";
      $.getJSON("index_two.php",function(data){
        $.each(data,function(index,item) 
        {
          items+="<option value='"+item.sno+"'>"+item.name+"</option>";
        });
        $("#a1_title").html(items); 
      });
          });



                </script>

              <select id="a1_title">
              <option>Default</option>
             </select>
```

in this code index_two.php is the name of page where i have written my select query that is fetching values from database...now i want to merge my these two codes...like that whenever i click on anchor tag in first code it displays a selectbox but with the values fetching from database....these two codes are working fine when i run them individually but  not working when i put them together... can someone suggest me a way......??

Comment: Please add http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i tried code but it is not working in that

Comment: Ok, but send us a jsfiddle link with your code...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FbUeD/1/       have a look at this link...in this is simply adding selectboxes whever i clcik on anchor tag but instead of the options the selectbox is showing...i want values from database....i have written my code above but how to make them work together is my problem

Comment: sir can you help me?//

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(function(){ 
     var items="";

     $('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();  //<--------use this instead of 'return false;'
        var sel = $('<select id="a1_title">').appendTo('body');

        $.getJSON("index_two.php",function(data){
          $.each(data,function(index,item) { 
            items+="<option value='"+item.sno+"'>"+item.name+"</option>";
          });

          $("#a1_title").html(items); 

        }); // getjson ends

     }); // click ends
 }); // doc ready ends
```

What seems to me you have put your data below `return false;`, so if this is the case then script execution stops whenever you `return false`, so i suggest you to use `e.preventDefault();` as suggested in the answer.

Comment: on click of an anchor tag no selectbox is coming and not fetching any value from database....and error is coming on this line....var arr = [{...}];

Comment: this is your array you have defined i just posted to tell you to use your array up there not this one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FbUeD/1/...this is my fiddles link....in this link only selectboxes are coming but i want selectboxes to dsiplay values from database....can you help me in that

Comment: i have wrote code above for fetching values from database but dont know how to make them work together....

Comment: but i dnt want to show that array....i want selectboxes to display values from database...array was just an example

Comment: okay what i understood now you want to show an selectbox then you want  to put options in it right.

Comment: yes the link that i sent you is now only showing static values in selectbox but i want them to fetch data from database